# How to restrict access to a page for non logged in users in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to restrict access to a particular static page in Magento for non logged in users. Does anyone have a solution. I looked at some extensions (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/MageParts/extension/3842/restrict_cms_pages and http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-permissions.html), but what I really need is much simpler.
Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You need to create your own module and rewrite the `Mage_Cms_PageController` controller (location in app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/PageController.php).

Here is a tutorial on how to do this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller

So you create your own module, let's say `CustomCms/PageAccess`. You will need to have the following controller:

```
class CustomCms_PageAccess_PageController extends Mage_Cms_PageController
{
    public function viewAction()
    {
        $pageId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false);
        if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() || $this->publiclyVisible($pageId) ) {
            parent::viewAction(); // default action
        } else {
            $this->_forward('noRoute'); // 404
        }
    }

    /*
     * this function should be in a helper
     * !!! Return false if the page should be visible only to logged in users !!!
     * @return bool
     */ 
    public function publiclyVisible($pageId) {
        return true; // here is where you check the page id
    }
}
```

If besides this, you want to set which pages to be publicly visible or protected directly from the admin panel, you need to add a custom field in the edit cms page.

Here is a tutorial on how to do this: http://blog.flexishore.com/2011/08/add-custom-field-to-cms-page/

After that, you need to modify the `publiclyVisible` function:

```
    public function publiclyVisible($pageId) {
        $page = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load(intval($pageId));
        // I'm asuming the new field is is_publicly_visible
        return (bool)$page->getIsPubliclyVisible(); 
    }
```

**Note:**

I haven't tested the tutorials I linked, but skimmed through them, and seem to be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I recently covered creating [a new Magento customer page](http://alanstorm.com/magento_create_customer_page) (self-link).  While the tutorial itself is a little heavy duty for your needs, it does have the magic line of code to check if a user is logged in or not.

So, assuming your "static-page" is operating in a Magento environment, the following PHP code should get you where you want to go.

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
{
    var_dump("Is Logged In");
}
else
{
    var_dump("In Not Logged in.  Exit or redirect or something.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For any page in Magento there will be a MOdule a controller and an action function.

For your specific page within controller action function you should apply  a code that checks whether a customer is logged in or not.
If not logged in redirect to some other page.

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
{
    continue...
}
else
{
    redirect....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answer is still relevant, but there is a FREE Magento extension that does just what you want. It is called Login Check.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/login-check.html